# Maven release not calling resources:resources plugin

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, maven-release-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I'm trying to deploy a maven project and upgrade the versions by executing the maven release plugin on TeamCity. I am able to successfully do this - however, the resources:resources plugin is no longer executed. Or more accurately, it is executed but not doing the expected changes. When I run a maven package or install however, it works. Not sure what it is I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code
Parent pom

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <releaseProfiles>releases</releaseProfiles>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                    <arguments>-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skipTests=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DCONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID=%build.counter% -DGIT_COMMIT=%build.vcs.number% -DGIT_BRANCH=%vcsroot.branch%</arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Child pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <!-- Adds ${buildNumber} to buildNumber.properties -->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>application_local.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

I run the following command:

```
mvn -B -e initialize release:branch release:clean release:prepare release:stage -DCONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID=%build.counter% -DGIT_COMMIT=%build.vcs.number% -DGIT_BRANCH=%vcsroot.branch%...
```

And I have in my child project in the src/main/resources folder a file called application-deployed.properties with the following lines which is what I want to change.

```
# build information by team city
child.propject.buildNumber=@CONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID@
child.propject.buildVersion=@GIT_COMMIT@
child.propject.buildBranch=@GIT_BRANCH@
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`maven-resources-plugin` doesn't have access to the parameters you pass in the command line. Reason for this is that `deploy` goal (which includes `resources:resources`, among others) is invoked by `maven-release-plugin` in a separate Maven execution.

In order to overcome this limitation, goals of `maven-release-plugin` accept [`arguments`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/stage-mojo.html#arguments) parameter that could be used to pass parameters to aforementioned separate Maven executions. Try to modify your command line the following way:

`mvn -B -e initialize release:branch release:clean release:prepare release:stage -Darguments="-DCONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID=%build.counter% -DGIT_COMMIT=%build.vcs.number% -DGIT_BRANCH=%vcsroot.branch%"`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work - I tried double and single quotes. It might be because I was executing the command from TeamCity

Comment: @sometimes24, I didn't notice that your maven-release-plugin already has `<arguments>` tag in the config. In this case the plugin ignores arguments passed via command line and uses the contents of the tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the following to the maven release plugin in the parent pom

```
<arguments>-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skipTests=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DCONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID=${CONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID} -DGIT_COMMIT=${GIT_COMMIT} -DGIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH}</arguments>
```

and then calling my initial command

```
mvn -B -e initialize release:branch release:clean release:prepare release:stage -DCONTINUOUS_BUILD_ID=%build.counter% -DGIT_COMMIT=%build.vcs.number% -DGIT_BRANCH=%vcsroot.branch%...
```